# ShareKit install via CocoaPods issue

Tags: ios, sharekit, cocoapods

I install SareKit via CocoaPods

I have got this exemption when I try to post my message to vk.com service:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'ShareKit has been refactored to be used as Xcode subproject. Please follow the updated installation wiki and re-add it to the project. Please do not forget to clean project and clean build folder afterwards. In case you use CocoaPods override - (NSNumber *)isUsingCocoaPods; method in your configurator subclass and return [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]'**

I tried to find updated installation wiki but without any successes.

I also added method below to my `DefaultSHKConfigurator` subclass and ShareKit works now but as I think just on 6.0 ios.

```
- (NSNumber *)isUsingCocoaPods {
    return [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
}
```

I got this error for iOS 5.1:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_SKStoreProductViewController
  Referenced from: /Users/alexander/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/2D844C7C-6864-4C4C-BFB8-F330AAE73EAE/test.app/test
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/StoreKit.framework/StoreKit
 in /Users/alexander/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/2D844C7C-6864-4C4C-BFB8-F330AAE73EAE/test.app/test
```

Comment: isUsingCocoaPods method helped ! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure that StoreKit.framework is marked optional. It is now in iOS 6.

Comment: yes, thanks. there are few frameworks that need to be optional.